# How to format datagridview when filling with linq2sql query

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I am looking to format the datagridview so I can hide and format certain column headers. The problem is I cant use the built in winforms dgv formatting because I am filling the grid from a straight linq query and not binding the table with the built in wizard. Here is my code to fill the table. How can I format the headers on the grid? Thanks!

```
var search = from s in db.trips
             orderby s.tripNo descending
             select s;

    dgvTripGrid.DataSource = search;
```

Comment: OmegaMan's answer is a great technique since it avoids a lot of the pain with linq anonymous types. In case you aren't aware of it you can also format grid columns after databinding by setting the column header text property (and by also hiding any unwanted columns) That mixed with the custom entity approach should give you all the control you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dynamic entity with the column (header) names which should be displayed and bind it here is an example:

```
BindingSource bindingSource1= new BindingSource();
private void LoadGrid()
{
    List<Data> dataListing = new List<Data>()
    {
        new Data() { Name = "Jabberwocky", Operation="Read", DateStart= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), DateEnd = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), Description="Process Started No errors"},
        new Data() { Name = "Space", Operation="Write", DateStart= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), DateEnd = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), Description="Final process remote allocation of 3000 items to main buffer."},
        new Data() { Name = "Stock Purchase", Operation="DataWarehousing", DateStart= DateTime.Now, DateEnd = DateTime.Now, Description="Shared data transport."}
    };

    var items = from dta in dataListing
        select new
        {
           OperationName = dta.Name,
           Start         = dta.DateStart.ToShortDateString(),
           End           = dta.DateEnd.ToShortDateString(),
           Operation     = dta.Operation,
           Description   = dta.Description
         };

    bindingSource1.DataSource = items;
    dataGridView1.DataSource  = bindingSource1;

    // Grid attributes
    dataGridView1.BorderStyle         = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

}
```

I show this example on my blog [C# Linq How To Load a Winform Control Using Dynamic Linq entitites](http://omegacoder.com/?p=435)